# What is the power supply protection on the Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: power

The previous RPi2 model has a 2A polyfuse after the power input.  The RPi3 now takes a USB power adapter up to 2.5A ( indicated as 2.4A in some references ).  Did they keep the polyfuse and increase its rating, or are they using something different for circuit protection?

Oddly, the RPi Foundation does not supply schematics or it would be a simple matter to check!

Answer (score 0):

And I wonder, what's with all those numbers (2.4-2.5 A) when micro USB B connector, through which RPi is powered, cannot pass more then 1.8 amps?! This looks like defective by design.